# Root state of redux/react-native app undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

When I add this line: `import { makePages } from './pages'`

I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'product' of undefined

**pages/index.js**

```
export * from './add'
export { makePages } from './model'
export * from './reducer'
```

**pages/model.js**

```
import type { RecordFactory, RecordOf } from 'immutable'
import { Record } from 'immutable'

export const makePages: RecordFactory<any> = Record({
  height: 5
})

export type Pages = RecordOf<any>
```

I'm not even using `makePages` in the file and it gets the error.

**product/model.js**

```
import type { RecordFactory, RecordOf } from 'immutable'
import { Record } from 'immutable'
import { makePages } from './pages'
const makeProduct: RecordFactory<any> = Record({
  pages: 3
})
let product = new makeProduct()
export { product }
```

Why does `import { makePages } from './pages'` cause the error?

[image]

Comment: It seems that „vepo“ is undefined, have you checked if it is exported properly in model.js?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the file path and it is correct. Model.js is the top code block in my question. I just added the file name then.

Comment: try `vepo.get('product')`

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev it didn’t work

Comment: please try to console.log the vepo somewhere, I agree with @PatrickHund you probably not correctly importing it. Or show please tree of the project.

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev Cheers I will when I get home. Fairly certain file paths in imports are correct as I checked them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I delete `export * from './add'` the error does not occur so I just need to make sure I'm exporting correctly. Possibly should export everything individually rather than all `*`